# What determines the pitch of the sound a spark makes?

Tags: electrostatics, acoustics

While being accosted by the various electrostatic discharges a person experiences in life, I have noticed that the pitch and timbre of their sound varies greatly.

What factors determine these properties of a spark's sound?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the gas surrounding it. If I am not wrong, you hear the sound because of the rapid expansion of the air molecules due to the heat generated by the spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Fig. 3 of https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00810828/document , it looks like the average frequency of sound from a spark decreases  (the average period increases) as the gap between the electrodes increases.

Comment: That you for this very interesting article. How did you find it?

Comment: @Etherian: The dumbest Google queries work the best:-) I used: spark acoustics